# Can file-uploads be accessed in RestrictedPython from PloneFormGen scripts?

Tags: plone, ploneformgen

Currently I'm trying to set up a Form to create a News-Item from. The Script works fine so far. Problems arise with the File-Field: As soon as I try to access the file via request.form['pub-core-cover'] I get an "Module AccessControl.ZopeGuards, line 67, in guarded_getitem".

I was advised to use a HelperView to bypass RestrictedPython which seems to be the issue here. This is pretty difficult for me due to the fact I have not developed an add-on product so far. Somehow I'm wondering as well if there is another possibility to make the File-Field feature in PFG work again within RestrictedPython. Otherwise the file-field becomes somehow obsolet.

CustomScript-Adapter (don't mind the german comments):

```
form = request.form

# ID des Zielverzeichnisses ist publikationen
target = context.publikationen

# Einmalige ID für das neu zu erstellende Objekt erstellen anhand des Datums + Uhrzeit
from DateTime import DateTime
uid = str(DateTime().millis())

# Titel und ID festlegen und damit News-Objekt erzeugen (Titel + Beschreibung)
title = form['author-prename'] + " " + form['author-surname']
desc = form['pub-core-title'] + " " + form['pub-core-subtitle']

target.invokeFactory("News Item", id = uid, title = title.upper(), description = desc, image = form['pub-core-cover'])

# Objekt aufspüren und ContentType festlegen
obj = target[uid]
obj.setContentType('text/html')

# Inhalt des News-Items setzen
obj.setText("<p>"+ form['pub-core-description'] +"<br /><br />Veröffentlicht: "+ form['pub-tech-year'] +"<br />ISBN: "+ form['pub-tech-isbn'] +"<br />Preis: "+ form['pub-tech-price'] +"<br />" + form['pub-tech-pages'] + " Seiten, " + form['pub-tech-binding'] + "</p>")

# Objekt veröffentlichen ohne den Initial-State im Workflow zu verändern
obj.portal_workflow.doActionFor(obj, 'publish', comment='Dieser Inhalt wurde über den PythonScriptAdapter von PloneFormGen automatisch publiziert.')

# Content reindexieren, um das neue Objekt anzuzeigen
obj.reindexObject()
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 127, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 47, in call_object
  Module Products.CMFFormController.FSControllerPageTemplate, line 91, in __call__
  Module Products.CMFFormController.BaseControllerPageTemplate, line 26, in _call
  Module Products.CMFFormController.FormController, line 384, in validate
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 47, in call_object
  Module Products.CMFFormController.FSControllerValidator, line 58, in __call__
  Module Products.CMFFormController.Script, line 145, in __call__
  Module Products.CMFCore.FSPythonScript, line 130, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 324, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 361, in _bindAndExec
  Module Products.PythonScripts.PythonScript, line 344, in _exec
  Module script, line 20, in fgvalidate_base
   - <FSControllerValidator at /breyer_verlag/fgvalidate_base used for /breyer_verlag/publikationen/publikation-hinzufuegen>
   - Line 20
  Module Products.PloneFormGen.content.form, line 566, in fgvalidate
  Module Products.PloneFormGen.content.form, line 607, in fgProcessActionAdapters
  Module Products.PloneFormGen.content.customScriptAdapter, line 187, in onSuccess
  Module Products.PloneFormGen.content.customScriptAdapter, line 218, in executeCustomScript
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 324, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 361, in _bindAndExec
  Module Products.PythonScripts.PythonScript, line 344, in _exec
  Module script, line 27, in create-publication
   - <PythonScript at /breyer_verlag/publikationen/publikation-hinzufuegen/create-publication/create-publication>
   - Line 27
  Module AccessControl.ZopeGuards, line 67, in guarded_getitem
KeyError: 'pub-core-cover'
```

I had no difficulties using an pretty similar code in Plone3. I would appreciate any help that gets me out of my misery.

Edit:
By the way:
Plone 4.05
PFG 1.72a

Comment: Isn't the file data actually in form['pub-core-cover-file']?  The KeyError is just saying that there is no value in the request for that key. You might want to inspect the request so you can see what's in it. Also, the addon http://pypi.python.org/pypi/uwosh.pfg.d2c might be of interest to you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No why should the variable be named form['pub-core-cover-file']? I declared it form['pub-core-cover']. For me the key problem is not 'pub-core-cover' but the line above which leads me to RestrictedPython whch I would like to bypass. Generally I would not like to use additional plugins but use the already existens faccilities of long-time products.

Comment: No, look at how the file uploads are implemented. It's actually '_file' that is appended to the key. I wrote d2c and had to work with this for file uploads. Check out http://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/uwosh.pfg.d2c/trunk/uwosh/pfg/d2c/content/savedataadapter.py

The error you are receiving is a KeyError: 'pub-core-cover' which means 'pub-core-cover' is not a key in the form dictionary.

Comment: Also, if the error was really from a problem with the python being restricted or you not having access to it, you'd get an Unauthorized exception, not a KeyError

Comment: Thanks again for your reply - and you were right! I tried "form['pub-core-cover-file']" which did not work because it is actually '_file' like you wrote in your second comment! Thanks mate - you helped me out of there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As vangheem stated it is not a RestrictedPython-Problem put has to do how PloneFormGen handles the data field. It is important to add `_file` to the variable name.